# Origin of "nopon" from Xenoblade chronicles

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles

I'm curious if "nopon" has any meaning. When I typed のぽん into Google Translate, it didn't come up with anything, and I haven't been able to find any information on the wikia page for the Nopon about where their name comes from. Is it just a made up name, or does it have some significance in Japan?

Also, I don't know why you would, but please don't spoil the series past [episode 28](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z0Fr1ZDB4bY&list=UUIJ6_pI8ZBc_xVMPYzwQz9g) of chuggaaconroy's Let's Play. If the answer to this question is a significant spoiler, I'd rather not know (I haven't played the game, I'm only watching it.)

Answer (score 1):

Nopon is a made-up word that refers to the race of creatures in Xenoblade Chronicles. [[1](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%83%8E%E3%83%9D%E3%83%B3%E6%97%8F)]

It has no meaning by itself in Japan or the Japanese language.

Source: I live in Japan and have native proficiency. I have also played the Xenoblade series.

Answer (score 0):

ノポン (katakana of のぽん) yields Nopon images only, so I would guess not.